# There is give complex number - considerations.

Tags: linear-algebra

$z=3e^{(3\pi/17)i}$.  Then:
a. $\left|\frac{1}{\overline{z}^2}\right|=\frac19$
b. there exists some $n\ge 1\in\mathbb{Z} $ such that $Re(z^n)=0$
c. there exists some $n\ge 1\in\mathbb{Z} $ such that $Im(z^n)=0$

a. $$\left|\frac{1}{\overline{z}^2}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\overline{z}}\right|^2= \frac{|1|^2}{|\overline{z}|^2}=\frac{1}{|\overline{z}|^2}=\frac{1}{|3e^{(3\pi/17)-i}|^2}=\frac{1}{|9e^{(6\pi/17)-i}|}=\frac{1}{9}$$   So a is true.
Tell me please, if my computations are ok ?  Maybe there exists other way to do it ?

b.  $$z=3e^{(3\pi/17)i}=|3|(\cos(3\pi/17)+i\sin(3\pi/17))$$
$$z^n = |3|^n\left(\cos\left(\frac{3n\pi}{17}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{3n\pi}{17}\right)\right)$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{3n\pi}{17}\right)=0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{3n\pi}{17}=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\Leftrightarrow 6n=17(2k+1)$$  Left side is even, right side is odd. So there is no such $n$ then $Re(z^n)=0$

c.  Analogously to previous point,

$$ \frac{3n\pi}{17}=k\pi$$ for $n=17, k=3 $  we have $\Im(z^n)=0.

Am I ok ? Maybe you have other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to wolfram alpha, and my own calculations, you are correct and there is no integer solution to $n$,

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%283n+pi+%2F17%29+%3D+0